# Use rundeck workflow global variable inside python script

Tags: rundeck

I'm build a workflow that have two main steps.
- Global log key value data filter:
Use this pattern: ^(CUSTOM-LOGFILE)=\s*(.+)$

- Step 1. bash script. Output a string that i need to use on second step.
- Step 2. Build global varible, using key/value data. 
  Value: ${data.CUSTOM-LOGFILE*}
  group: export
  Name: CUSTOM-LOGFILE
- Step 3. python script that takes all arguments throught environment variables (RD_OPTION_* env variales). For example, inside the script I need to take the CUSTOM-LOGFILE value.
  I tested it in a few ways, but I cannot take the content of the CUSTOM-LOGFILE. If I print the env variables through python, I cannot see the CUSTOM-VARIABLE env defined

How can I use a global variable inside a python script like option env variable (RD_OPTION_XXXX) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Works if you use `@data.yourdata@` or `@option.youroption@` I leave an example with both ways (using python script on Rundeck):

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt1' value='Rundeck' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>0966cf1c-2b38-44fd-8c82-997803c64882</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorldPY</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "DATA=Rundeck"</exec>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(DATA)\s*=\s*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.py</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# using data
print("The data value is: @data.DATA@")

# using options
print("The option value is: @option.opt1@")]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/usr/bin/python3.8</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>0966cf1c-2b38-44fd-8c82-997803c64882</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```